# Simplified l'Hospital: please can you check my proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I tried to show:

If $f,g: [a,b) \to \mathbb R$ are differentiable and $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^+} g(x) = 0 $ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} {f'(x) \over g'(x)} = L$. Also assume that $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous. Then $\lim_{x \to a^+} {f(x) \over g(x)} = L$.

Please can you check my proof:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous, ${f'(a) \over g'(a)} = L$ and for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta$ such that $0<|a-x|<\delta$ implies $|{f'(x) \over g'(x)} - L| < \varepsilon$. By the mean value theorem, for $\delta'<\delta$, there exists $c \in (a,a+\delta')$ such that ${f'(c) \over g'(c)} = {f(a+\delta')-f(a) \over g(a + \delta') - g(a)} = {f(a+\delta') \over g(a+\delta')}$. Hence for $\delta' < \delta$:
$$ |{f(a+\delta') \over g(a+\delta')} -L| = |{f'(c) \over g'(c)} -L| < \varepsilon$$

Can this proof be simplified more?

Comment: No, this is as short as it gets, and has a good style. One small correction: You want to use the extended mean value theorem. The simple version is for $g(x)=x$.